# I have a outdoor circuit with multiple GFCI’s, all working but no lights are on

Tags: gfci

I have an outdoor circuit with 5 total outlets, three are GFCI with two lights. I recently connected a bug zapper & timer to one of the GFCI outlets and noticed that none of the the lights are lit but all of the outlets are working, is this normal ? Shouldn’t one of the led’s be solid green. I have tested and reset the outlets with the same outcome.

Comment: One circuit, one GCFI.  Keeps life simple.  An outdoor circuit must be GFCI protected, does not mean every outlet needs to be GFCI.  One will protect the circuit(and probably want it inside, for weather protection).

Comment: What brand/model are the GFCI outlets? That will help people identify the expected behavior of the indicator lights to determine if yours is unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the make/model of the GFCI/receptacle. Many older ones do not have any lights. A GFCI at its essence is a very simple device, as opposed to an AFCI. So there is not necessarily any need for the relatively fancy circuitry that would, as a side-effect, provide an "on/good" indicator light.

Recent code requires *self testing* GFCI, whether at the breaker or receptacle (or in between). This requires more sophisticated circuitry, plus a green (doesn't *have* to be green, but that makes the most sense to me) light as an indicator of "all good" is helpful as an indication that the self-test has run properly.

You can easily have different makes/models of GFCI/receptacles in a house, so it is quite possible that you have indicator lights on the kitchen and bathroom GFCI/receptacles but not on the outdoor receptacles.

As noted in some comments, if wired properly, multiple receptacles can share GFCI protection provided in a breaker/GFCI or in one GFCI/receptacle. That can save some money initially as well as, in the case of outdoor receptacles, keep the electronics of the GFCI out of heat/cold/humidity/rain/etc.

Comment: Think the OP is saying the indicator lights they do have, have stop being lit/working.  If OP is right all three with indicator lights have the lights go dead, but not the outlets.  Seems odd for three to go dead together.